# Get rid of "Incompatible pointer" warning caused by typedef

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-warnings

I'm really pedantic when it comes to compiler warnings. They help me to debug a lot of issues, so I try and get rid of all of them.

I have 2 child structs, let's call them `ChildA` and `ChildB` and a base struct `Base`.

```
// predefines.h
typedef struct sBase Base;
typedef struct sChildA ChildA;
typedef struct sChildB ChildB;

// base.h
typedef struct sBase {
    // Base fields
} Base;

// child_a.h
typedef struct sChildA {
    Base* base;
    // other things
} ChildA;

// child_b.h
typedef struct sChildB {
    Base* base;
    // other things
} ChildB;
```

Should be just fine, huh? And it works, except it generates so many warnings all around my code, that **other warnings, I just can't notice them in my IDE, because I just see so much yellow**.

I have a lot of functions like:

```
void do_something(Base* base) {
    // Code code code
}

do_something(instance_of_child_a); // Warning here
```

Is there any way to make the compiler happy without disabling warnings of this type? Thanks a bunch.

**edit:** Here is the warning:

> note: expected ‘Base * {aka struct sBase *}’ but argument is of type
>   ‘ChildA * {aka struct sChildA *}’  void do_something(LitBase* base);

Comment: Where are the warnings? Are you trying to establish the "is-a" relationship in C?

Comment: @babon added the warning. And I'm not trying to get is-a relationship. Code doesn't use Child methods if it doesn't know that it's a Child instance. Real code Base handles memory related things, and Child classes use that memory management for their needs.

Comment: `do_something(&instance_of_child_a.base);` or use `void*` and casts `void do_something(void *x) { struct sBase *base = x; /* ... */ }`

Comment: ChildA and Base are independent types. Your method will work only if ChildA and ChildB are derived from Base.

Comment: @P.W what do you call "derived"? The classes have Base struct as their first member. It's called type punning. And it always worked for me in other cases, but I had to use typedef here, to resolve circle dependencies.

Comment: @pmg that works ofc, but doing that x1000 times is not the best way, if there is another one :thinking:

Comment: Do you really need `"predefines.h"` and repeating the `typedef`s?

Comment: @pmg yes, I had some really nasty circle dependencies. I didn't find another way to resolve them but predefining.

Comment: @egordorichev:  The error is not caused just because of typedef.

Comment: @P.W I have another one of type punning examples in the project, and it doesn't generate any warnings. And it's defined the same way, except typedef. If you think its not caused by it, what is it caused by?

Comment: @egordorichev: The problem is that the pointers are not inter-convertible for independent types. See your example without typedefs. https://godbolt.org/z/-03qVK

Comment: Hm, thats weird, because it compiles just fine on my native setup. Let me see what I messed up :x

Comment: Here we go @P.W, sorry, I forgot to include *. Here is a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/7cQK7k

Comment: @egordorichev: It does issue a warning. And with `-pedantic-errors` option (which means strict conformity to the standard) it issues an error. https://godbolt.org/z/jjAWxy

Comment: Yes. But my question is, is there any way to get rid of warning for ONLY this type, because in other cases this warning saves from hours of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the warning because `ChildA*` is not compatible with `Base*`. They are obviously different struct types. And since they are not compatible (in this context meaning identical), the compiler cannot implicitly convert between them. It is not some annoying "false positive" but a C language violation that shouldn't be ignored. Many compilers will give an error and refuse to produce a binary.

You have to use an explicit cast or simply pass on the `.base` member manually.

Another alternative to the explicit cast would be a wrapper macro:

```
void base_do_something (Base* base);

#define do_something(x)                                       \
  base_do_something (                                         \
    _Generic( (x), ChildA*: &(x)->base, ChildB*: &(x)->base ) \
  )
```

Or equivalent:

```
#define do_something(x)                                       \
  base_do_something (                                         \
    _Generic( (x), ChildA*: (Base*)(x), ChildB*: (Base*)(x) ) \
  )
```

As fishy as the latter example looks, it is actually valid per C17 6.7.2.1 §15. And it doesn't violate strict aliasing since `ChildA` etc is an aggregate containing `Base` among its members. If you aren't a language lawyer, go with the 1st example :)